# Python import downloaded modules

Tags: python, import

I have no idea if this is where i should post this but anyways

I have downloaded flask from github and have no idea how to make it so it can be imported into python so i can use it.

Comment: Is it a wheel? You can install it via `pip install path_to_wheel`. Also why not installing it via pip `pip install flask`

Comment: @dmb where/how do i do that?

Comment: In the terminal. For windows open the run diaog `WindowsKey+R` type `cmd` then enter. Now type the above and replace `path_to_wheel` to the path where you have stored the wheel, or just `pip install flask`